# Default HTTP request is not working on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android

I'm doing an HTTP request in an Android application using this code:

```
    try 
    {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(<URL>);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        parseResponce(responseText);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("http post error : ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

The request is working on android 2.3, but I'm not receiving a response in Android 4.0.4. 
 Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're having troubles because you perform network operation on UI thread. Try using AsyncTask or Java threading framework.

Comment: i'm already doing this inside a class implements runable and i'm that pic of code is inside the run method .. thanks anyways

Comment: @user1726922 I guess you don't really understand the difference between Runnable and Thread. The former is just a piece of work to be done. And you need another thread. So you need to pass your Runnable to new Thread.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html).

The problem is most likely that you are performing a potentially expensive operation on the main UI thread. There's no way of knowing how long the HTTP request could take, so you should offload the work to a background thread using an `AsyncTask`, for example.

The reason why this works on Gingerbread but not on ICS is because Android 4.0 is much stricter about abuse against the UI thread (and it will go as far as to crash your application if you abuse it too much).

Comment: i think you got me wrong it is working on Gingerbread but it won't work on ics .. but thanks anyways

Comment: oops... sorry, that was a typo on my part. I meant to say "working on gingerbread but not on ICS).